# Odd behavior with SKStoreProductViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to use SKStoreProductViewController to open the App Store modally within my app. I have looked at many examples on the web, and there are two ways people are doing this.

```
 SKStoreProductViewController *storeController = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
                [storeController setDelegate:self];
            //set product parameters
            //must be a number wrapped in a string
            NSDictionary *productParameters = @{ SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier : @"36372693196"};
               [storeController loadProductWithParameters:productParameters completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error)  {
                    if (result) {
                        //show
                        [self presentViewController:storeController animated:YES completion:nil];
                    }else {
                        NSLog(@"ERROR WITH STORE CONTROLLER %@\n", error.description);
                        //redirect to app store
                        //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[[self class] appStoreURL]];
                    }
                }];
```

If I do it this way ^^ nothing happens. The if (result) or else statement within the block is never executed.

I also see people passing in nil for the completion block, and presenting the view controller modally immediately after this like below:

```
 SKStoreProductViewController *storeController = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
                [storeController setDelegate:self];
            //set product parameters
            //must be a number wrapped in a string
            NSDictionary *productParameters = @{ SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier : @"36372693196"};
                [storeController loadProductWithParameters:productParameters completionBlock:nil];
        [self presentViewController:storeController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When I present the view controller, the code inside the block for loadProductWithParameters executes. I am extremely confused at this point..How do I check for success or failure if the block isn't run until after I present it.

Lastly, I read you should execute the loadProductWithParameters in a background thread. I tried this as well. The second option is the only one that brought up the modal - with a Cannot connect to iTunes message from the simulator and device. I have tried multiple app ids. What is going on? How do I get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're first code should work just fine. However in iPhone Simulator, the iTunes Store often returns an error.

I've tested your first code on the iPhone (with an other identifier) and it works just fine, but the `SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier` you've provided (36372693196) doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: If the Identifier you pass in is not correct or not valid for the iTunes store you are under, the controller will do nothing.

Comment: Correct, it will display an error in the completionblock. Try an other identifier, eg 495922875, and it works just fine.

Comment: I had an issue where it wasn't going into the block at all - unless the identifier was correct. This is why it was such a pain to troubleshoot.

Comment: Also note that, according to the docs, SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier should be an NSNumber, not an NSString.

Comment: I'm having this problem even with a valid identifier on iOS 9.3. On iOS 11.0 it works perfectly fine. Any idea what else might be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The `completionBlock` never gets called -- on either the simulator or a real device -- if the iTunes item identifier isn't valid.  That would seem to make the `result` and `error` parameters useless so I would say that this is a bug.

The simulator would also seem to have additional problems in that it will not present any content even when the identifier is valid (and works on a device).

Comment: You are absolutely right about this..unfortunately it took me a while to figure this out as its not clear in the documentation

Comment: I'm having this problem even with a valid identifier on iOS 9.3. On iOS 11.0 it works perfectly fine. Any idea what else might be wrong?